# Update Select Menu based off another Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of states (USA) that includes Canadian provinces,

```
<select>
<optgroup label="United States">
    <option value="AL">Alabama (AL)</option><option value="AK">Alaska (AK)</option><option value="AE">APO state (AE)</option><option value="AO">APO state (AO)</option><option value="AP">APO state (AP)</option><option value="AZ">Arizona (AZ)</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Canada">
<option value="AB">Alberta (AB)</option><option value="BC">British Columbia (BC)</option><option value="MB">Manitoba (MB)</option><option value="NB">New Brunswick (NB)</option><option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador (NL)</option></optgroup>
</select>
```

Then I have another select menu that includes 2 options, USA & Canada. (USA is default selected)

I want that if Canadian province is selected, disable USA as country in second select menu. and if Canada is selected in second select menu, remove USA states from first select menu.

I only found ways to populate the second select menu after choosing the first (like this http://jsfiddle.net/FK7ga/), but what I try is to show all by default, and update after selecting either one.

Comment: @j08691 see below http://stackoverflow.com/a/16822289/1058222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#filter").on("change", function() {
    $states = $("#states");
    $states.find("optgroup").hide().children().hide();
    $states.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "']").show().children().show();
    $states.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "'] option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
});
```

**[See this working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/emb2p/)**

Answer (score 1):

@letiagoalves:

I've just edited your fiddle by changing `show/hide` to `attr('disable','disable');` and `removeAttr('disable');` This causes the list to stay, but prevent the wrong state group to get selected.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to make it work as I wanted, with the help of [@letiagoalves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819022/update-select-menu-based-off-another-selection/16819707#16819707), Below is the code

```
$("#countries").on("change", function () 
{
    if ($("#countries").find(":selected").val())
    {
        $states = $("#states");
        $states.find("optgroup").hide().children().hide();
        $states.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "']").show().children().show();
        $states.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "'] option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
    }
    else
    {
        $states.show().children().show().children().show();
    }
});

$("#states").on("change", function () {
    $countries = $("#countries");

    if ($("#states").find("option:selected")) 
    {
        var c = $("#states").find("option:selected").parent().attr("label");
        $countries.find("option[value='" + c + "']").prop("selected", true);
        $("#countries").change();
    }
});
```

Still trying to make it work with [@Alex-Amthor's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819022/update-select-menu-based-off-another-selection/16820311#16820311) of disable, will update answer if I succeed. meanwhile here is a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emb2p/13/)